# Block access to a file

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i want to make a program which block any file(like autorun.inf),so that no other program can read from it(just like a way,antivirus do) with c++ in windows.
please help me.
thanks.

Comment: You may wish to start your research with the [wikipedia article on rootkits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rootkit).

Comment: @sarnold: I think the OP wants to make it so that certain files can be read only by the OP's program, not make them invisible. I would not be at all happy with any program that exhibits rootkit-like behavior.

Comment: @In silico, ah! That makes more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open a file with a `dwShareMode` of 0, which will

> Prevents other processes from opening a file or device if they request delete, read, or write access.

So once your process opens the file, no other process will be able to open it, delete it, etc.

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

either set the NTFS ACLs on the file

or

use CreateFile() to open the file with dwShareMode=0 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could encrypt the file. If it's unreadable it's unusable!

A simple xor will do.